# How to mark the current method in a log file?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, obfuscation

I'm writing an exception logger class. My question is: what to use to mark the current method? Except it's name, cause the code will be obfuscated, so it can't be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can invent your own attribute and decorate your methods with the attribute.
Something like `[MethodName("WriteXMLData")]`

You can then have the logger class perform some reflection on the MemberInfo object passed to it during logging.

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) is a great tutorial for defining and querying your own attributes.

Comment: Of course, if you’re going to do that, you might as well tell your obfuscator to stop renaming things. Or just stop using obfuscators entirely.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at some of the logging frameworks out there. I'm partial to [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/). It's easy to configure and has a lot of flexibility.

Answer (score -1):

you can get all the data u need about the specific exception, and log it to a data source:

here u can extract a little info on a given exception:

```
protected void Application_Error( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    Exception Exc = null;
    try
    {
        Exc = Server.GetLastError();
        if(Exc.InnerException != null)
            Exc = Exc.InnerException;

        // Method name + line number + column
        System.Diagnostics.StackTrace trace = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(Exc, true);
        string ExtraData = "Name : {0}, Line : {1}, Column : {2}";
        ExtraData = String.Format(ExtraData, trace.GetFrame(0).GetMethod().Name, trace.GetFrame(0).GetFileLineNumber(), trace.GetFrame(0).GetFileColumnNumber());
        // exception message
        Exc.Message;
        // page name
        Request.Url.ToString();
        // stack trace
        Exc.StackTrace; 
    }
}
```